# How to test the component refresh behavior with react-testing-library?

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm writing a test for a component that takes a few props such as "isLoading", "clients" and "refreshClients". refreshClients is defined like this:

```js
function refreshClients() {
  setIsLoading(true)
  getClients().then(response => {
    setClients(response)
    setIsLoading(false)
  })
}
```

clients and isLoading are states from the parent component that are used as props of the child component. The client component also gets the refreshClients prop, which allows it to update its own props (isLoading and clients), through the function passed in by the parent component.

This is one of the use cases: after taking an action over a client, like deletion, the component will call refreshClients, which should take care of reloading the clients table displayed in the component. While the new listing is being loaded the table isn't displayed (isLoading is true). The component works well, however I'm unsure on how to properly test it using testing-library. I'm basically calling rerender in the tests but I feel there should be a way to replicate this behavior in the tests...

Is there a way to create states to pass as props to the tested component? Or is there another recommended approach to handle cases like this?

In case it makes it easier to visualize the idea, here is a complete simple example of how it would work:

```js
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom'
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [clients, setClients] = useState(['david', 'sara']);
  const refreshClients = () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setClients(['john', 'mary'])
      setIsLoading(false)
    }, 1000)
  }
  return <ClientsTable isLoading={isLoading} clients={clients} refreshClients={refreshClients} />
}

function ClientsTable({ isLoading, clients, refreshClients}) {
  const deleteClient = () => {
    console.log('TODO: delete client')
    refreshClients()
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <p>Loading... please wait</p>}
      {!isLoading && clients.map(client => (
        <div>{client} <button onClick={deleteClient}>delete</button></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root')
).render(<App />)
```

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete code.

Comment: I've added a simple sample app that illustrates the idea to the description of the question